juju lxd machine pending
I used the "juju bootstrap" command to set up my juju-controller on localhost. Then, I created a model named "test" and tried to create a machine using "juju add-machine". Furthermore, I attempted to deploy an LXD container with "juju add-machine lxd:0". Unfortunately, the machine "0/lxd/0" is still pending.I am not using MAAS.My juju version is 3.4.0-genericlinux-amd64.


Happened to me equally. I don't know how to fix it properly (and if it is not a coincidence), but try to connect to the machine with juju ssh 0 for example, and maybe to enter in the container sudo lxc exec container bash. Several seconds later my machine received magically its started state.
